# Is this Rick & Morty question on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, specific-question

[This](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/151986/earth-disappears-rick-morty) question - although asking about an on-topic work of sci-fi, the question is purely based on a real world question. Should this question be closed as off topic for seeking "*Scientific Explanations*", or should it be deemed on topic due to the work it's about?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is our actual policy on science questions?](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/7364/31394) (the current policy on which science-based questions are on-topic and which aren't).

Answer (score 2):

### No

The question here is ***"How long would the astronauts on the ISS have survived? And what would they have died from?"*** which seems to be asking from an out-of-universe perspective. That makes it off-topic since we only deal with *fictional* universes.

- **[What is our actual policy on science questions?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7364/what-is-our-actual-policy-on-science-questions)**

The issue of astronaut survival sounds exactly the sort of thing that [Space:SE](https://space.stackexchange.com/) deal with, so it's worth prodding the user in that direction with a comment, albeit their question isn't migration-worthy.

---

Had they asked ***"How long did the astronauts on the ISS survive? And what did they die from?"***, that would be perfectly acceptable.

Comment: I don't understand the difference between the two questions you have suggested as on/off-topic, one seems to be that past tense of the other?

Comment: @Edlothiad - One is asking how long they would survive **in the real world**, the latter is asking how long they survived in the fictional world of Rick and Morty.

Comment: Ah I see now, thanks. Would it be acceptable to edit the question to get it re-opened?

Comment: @edlothiad - It would not only be acceptable but positively encouraged.