# How is this question not Too Broad?

Tags: discussion, questions

[What's the technical explanation for gravity to exist inside a spacecraft in science fiction?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7682/whats-the-technical-explanation-for-gravity-to-exist-inside-a-spacecraft-in-sci)

This old question is still open. Can I know why it is not *Too Broad*? There can literally be thousands of different theories and it is ever-growing.

Comment: If you notice something like that, go ahead and throw a close vote on and it will get added to the review queue.  We just had a *Matrix* question maybe a week or two ago that was too "real-world", inspired by an older question that was also too "real-world" but was popular and put in before that policy came about.

Comment: It doesn't have any single answer, because there's many possible answers depending on setting and hardness (that is, if it's hard sci fi, where everything must be based in current science or soft sci fi where anything can be handwaved away with technobabble).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### It is.

This question has two separate issues, either of which would be sufficient for closure.

1. It's too broad. As noted in the question, there are innumerable possible technical explanations for artificial gravity, depending on the work. It's like "How do superheroes fly?" or "How does a sorcerer bind a demon?"
2. The way it is worded strongly suggests it is asking for explanations about how a technology could work in "the real world," which are [off-topic per our policy on science questions.](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7367/51379)

As such, this question should be closed.

Keep in mind that this question was asked in 2011, in the earlier days of this site. Back then, we didn't have the same criteria for closing questions as we do now, or as solid community standards. There are many old questions still open that would be closed if they were asked today.

Comment: Or left open for historical relevance? Although I don't really know how that policy works.

Comment: @Edlothiad - I agree that it has historical relevance, but it need not be left open. Even if closed, I believe, it won't be deleted, due to its overwhelmingly positive score, answers, etc. It will just prevent people from adding new answers of dubious quality, or thinking that it's a a good idea to ask such questions now. Questions of historical value (or those subject to a great deal of vandalism) do sometimes get locked, but that's not really necessary here.