# Would this specific modification to this question make it answerable on this site?

Tags: discussion, scope

The question

[How is fission drive possible?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/263410/how-is-fission-drive-possible)

was closed for being about real-world science, because it seemed to ask about how fission drives worked in general.

Would it become answerable if it were formulated to ask what, if anything, the text of the work said about how
the fission drives *in the story* worked?

Comment: As the question was closed, I've made the edit described and it seems to be on its way to being reopened.

Comment: For the record, I don't believe it to be answerable (e.g. what's on the page is all the info we get), but that's a whole different issue :-)

Answer (score 3):

Yes. The major problem with this question is that it asks...

> *Putting obvious problems with that approach aside, are there other possibilities or interpretations of a "fission drive"?*

...which is obviously asking about real-world science (which we've decided is [off-topic](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7364/what-is-our-actual-policy-on-science-questions)).

**If they restricted the question to explanations of the workings *in the novel*, that would immediately bring it back on-topic.**

Comment: Not that this really needs more justification, but it would also mean that the question would have a single correct answer, and single body of canon to source it from, all of which makes it much more tractable.